# How to pick a group.id for my consumer group in an apache kafka cluster that is used by many other consumers?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have been provided with a kafka cluster url for consuming messages, but we as the a consumer-side have multiple cluster nodes.

For making sure that each message will be processed once only we are going to use a common `group.id` shared by our consumer group. Also we will Explicitly Commit Offsets.

My question is: how do we make sure that we will not pick a `group.id` that is already been used by other consumer groups? Is there a naming convention followed that ensures `group.id` uniqueness or should we contact the Kafka cluster maintainer for this?

Answer (score 1):

There are character restrictions (like no spaces or symbols other than `[_.-]` group), but there is no general "convention" that is used outside of what your cluster maintainer might know.

You can view all existing groups using

```
kafka-consumer-groups --list
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Could my consumer group, somehow ensure that the specific `group.id` will not be used in the future (intentionally or unintentionally) by other consumers of the topic? Because this would obviously result in my system loosing messages.

Comment: You'd need to setup topic authorization such that unauthorized clients cannot consume from the same topics. However, for authorized clients, that wouldnt prevent them from still using the same group id since they would just appear to be new consumers of the same group as if you'd ran them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Many companies get around this problem by generally setting an application's Kafka consumer `group.id` to the application's name.